# How to make bar chart animation where all bars grow at the same speed?

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I wanted to find a way to make this:
A bar chart where all the bars start growing slowly at the same speed, so you don't know which one is going to finish higher. Each one stops when it reaches it's height.

I was looking at chart.js and morris charts but I haven't found a way to do it there. If you know how to do it in chart.js or in any other library, let me know!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, no one answered, but I managed to do it.
In case anyone needs it:

Using chartist:

```js
// Prepare data, labels on the x axis and series on the y axis
var data = {
  labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  series: [
    [5, 2, 4, 2, 0]
  ]
};

// Create chart
var chart = new Chartist.Bar('#results', data);

// Create animation
chart.on('draw', function(d) {
  if(d.type === 'bar') {
    var total_duration = 5000 // [ms]
    var max_value = Math.max.apply(null,d.series);
    var speed = total_duration/max_value;
    d.element.animate({
      y2: {
        begin: 0,
        // The duration of the animation of each bar is set to be
        // proportional to its value, this way all bars go at the 
        // same speed.
        dur: d.series[d.index]*speed,
        from: d.y1,
        to: d.y2,
        easing: Chartist.Svg.Easing.linear
      }
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.10.1/chartist.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartist/0.10.1/chartist.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="ct-chart ct-perfect-fourth" id="results"></div>
```